# Element type replace with Mootools

Tags: mootools

One of my web page carries multiple forms with same elements under different form id such as

```
<form method="post" action="" style="" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" id="comment-form-1">

    <textarea rows="1" cols="45" id="body" name="body" ></textarea>

    <button class="post-comment-sml" type="submit" id="submit" name="submit"></button>
</form>
<form method="post" action="" style="" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" id="comment-form-2">

    <textarea rows="1" cols="45" id="body" name="body" ></textarea>

    <button class="post-comment-sml" type="submit" id="submit" name="submit"></button>
</form>
---
<form method="post" action="" style="" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" id="comment-form-n">

    <textarea rows="1" cols="45" id="body" name="body" ></textarea>

    <button class="post-comment-sml" type="submit" id="submit" name="submit"></button>
</form>
```

Here can I replace all submit button in varios form with normal button type as follows

```
<form method="post" action="" style="" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" id="comment-form-1">

    <textarea rows="1" cols="45" id="body" name="body" ></textarea>

    <button class="post-comment-sml" type="button" id="submit" name="submit"></button>
</form>
```

Comment: That HTML needs some love.  Elements can't share the same ID.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElements("button.post-comment-sml").set("type", "button")`

... not working for you or am I missing something?

keep in mind IE sometimes does not like certain types being changed. dont remember atm if it affects this case but its worth a shot.

Comment: I think IE only stops you from changing the `type` on a password input (to *and* from).

Comment: `input[type=text,value=c:\autoexec.bat]` > `input[type=file]` would be seriously unfunny :)